# Correct JSON for points with custom attributes and 3+ values?

Tags: highcharts

I am a bit confused by the documentation regarding the notation for point values when it comes to 3+ value charts such as HeatMap and BoxPlot.

I see that point values can be supplied as n length arrays:

```
data: [
                [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
                [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080]...
            ]
```

And that they can be config objects with additional/custom properties:

```
data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            x: 1,
            y: 3
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            x: 2,
            y: 5
        }]
```

But how does one use the config object notation for HeatMap/BoxPlot when the only documented value properties seem to be 'x' and 'y'?

Is there a supported property of the config object that will be interpreted as the n length array? Something like this?

```
data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            values: [1,2,3]
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            values: [4,5,6]
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of chart.

For HeatMap ([reference](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/heatmap)):

> A heat map has an X and Y axis like any cartesian series. The point definitions however, take three values, `x`, `y` as well as `value`, which serves as the value for color coding the point. These values can also be given as an array of three numbers.

In other words you could do `{ x: 0, y: 1, value: 10 }` or `[0,1,10]`.

For BoxPlot ([reference](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/box-plot-series)):

> Each point in a box plot has five values: low, q1, median, q3 and high. Highcharts recognizes three ways of defining a point:
>
> - Object literal. The X value is optional.
>
>   `{ x: Date.UTC(2013, 1, 7), low: 0, q1: 1, median: 2, q3: 3, high: 4 }`
> - Array of 5 values. The X value is inferred.
>
>   `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`
> - Array of 6 values. The X value is the first position.
>
>   `[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 7), 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was scouring the API docs but did not think to look in the "Chart and Series Type" docs section. May I suggest that it would be nice to have a cross-link from the API docs for 'series.data' with a note indicating that some specifics of the various series datapoint flavors can be found there? As a developer my instinct for the next place to look would be down into source code not up into a higher level area of documentation.